# Detect which plugin automatically write the closing comment character just after I write the opening one

Tags: vim

I have installed the [spf13](http://vim.spf13.com/) package with tons of plugins for testing.
When I type a ( or a " or anything that looks like the beginning of a comment, a plugin adds the corresponding closing character ) or ". 
How could I find which plugin is the "culprit" ? In general, what is the logical way to investigate such category of question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim "distributions" like *spf-13* and *Janus* lure you with a quick install and out-of-the-box settings, but you pay the price with increased complexity (you need to understand both Vim's runtime loading scheme and the arbitrary conventions of the distribution) and inflexibility (the distribution may make some things easier, but other things very difficult). Vim is incredibly customizable, using someone else's customization makes no sense.

That said, the functionality is from one of the available *auto close* plugins that apparently ships with spf13. In general, if you need to find out which plugin is behind a mapping, the `:verbose map` command will tell you where the mapping comes from. In your case, this is likely triggered by the `(` key in insert mode, so the query would be:

```
:verbose imap (
```

Comment: Thanks for the verbose hint. I found the culprit between your first and second answer. It was vim-autoclose.

Answer (score 1):

The only sane way to deal with plugins is to go shopping *yourself* when you need something that's not available in Vim (assuming you actually tried to find a built-in solution to your problem first) and read the plugin's documentation thoroughly. That way, you'll take control of *your* configuration and never come across an unexpected behavior.

Distributions like the one you installed pretend to make configuration simpler by forcing all kinds of plugins and settings and unnecessary complexity layers onto unsuspecting newbies thus actively preventing proper learning.

I suggest you drop that crap as soon as possible.

As for "the logical way to investigate such category of question", you'll have to go through all your plugins to find the plugin responsible for that unwanted behavior.

FWIW, I *know* the name of the plugin but it is *very* important for you to go through that process *on your own*.